# Debug Exception Breakpoints in multiple sub packages

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

I get the following error in my application:

> Error has occured with message:
>   [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted]
>   [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted]
>   Could not commit transaction.

Somewhere in my code I expect there is an exception being thrown that is being swallowed without re-throwing or printing the stacktrace and that marks my transaction as dirty. The set of code under suspicion is quite large (very large) so just stepping through it won't cut it.

Eclipse supports breaking whenever a exception is thrown, caught or uncaught. Problem is that I'm running in the context of JBoss which also throws exceptions. Is there a way with the exception filtering to tell Eclipse to *only* break on code that is in a certain package and its sub packages. The keyword here being sub packages.

I can't add just the packages I want because the list of packages is large. Hundreds of potential ones. All of our packages start with za.co so was wondering if there was a way to specify something like za.co.** which would match za.co and all of the sub packages.

Comment: If your going to downvote my question, please leave a comment suggesting on why and how to improve it.

Comment: I think it's a fine question. Don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So presumably you have already added an exception breakpoint.

- In breakpoints window Right click the breakpoint
- Select "Breakpoint properties"
- Select Filtering
- Click "Add Package"
- Choose the package(s) you want to check in

Comment: Thanks TedTrippin. Yes I have done that already. Please see the updated question that is a little more specific to exactly what I'm after.

Comment: You should have really have had a try yourself, its what I did. Instead of "Add package" just use "Add" then you can specify "za.co.*" which means za.co and all sub packages. Dont forget to check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse debug perspective, click the 'J!' button on the 'Breakpoints' view and type java.lang.Exception.

This will cause you to catch ALL exceptions, of course, so you can right-click the new breakpoint in the list and select 'Breakpoint properties'. In the filtering section, add a package filter.